# Check isunique attribute of an entity in a .net core api

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I have this Entity

```
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class AccountType:IEntityBase
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the code to test (simplified):

```
public async Task<string> CreateEntity(string entityName)
{
    TEntity entity = new TEntity { Name = entityName };
    try
    {
        //Code to save entity in database
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex) when (ex.InnerException.HResult == -2147467259)
    {                        
        //Code to deal with exception
    }
    return entity.Id;
}
```

What should be the unit test to implement?
When I insert the same name, the `DbException` is not raised (so that it works out of the test project).
Thanks.

Comment: You insert 2 entities and check that the second entity insert gives the first entity's id as a result (and not a new one)?

Comment: Doesn't work, 2nd id is different.

Comment: I suggest you could check the generated migration code to see what's the table ef core generated the table.